# Videos not playing in certain browsers (I.E.10)

Tags: html, video, browser

i am trying to get a video to play in all browsers, however while it works perfectly fine in chrome, in firefox it comes up with an error, and in I.E. 10 the video box loads up but does not run

here is the code :

```
<video id="myVideo" width="100%"  controls="controls">
                        <source src="..\resources\Tutorial\video.ogg"  type='video/ogg; codecs=&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;' />
                        <source src="..\resources\Tutorial\video.mp4" type='video/mp4;'/>
                    </video>
```

how can i get my video to play in all browsers ?

Thanks guys :)

tried :

```
<video id="myVideo" width="100%"  controls="controls">
                        <source src="..\resources\Tutorial\video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
                        <source src="..\resources\Tutorial\video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' /> 
                        <source src="..\resources\Tutorial\video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' /> 
                        Video tag not supported. Download the video <a href="..\resources\Tutorial\video.webm">here</a>. 
                    </video>
```

but no luck either, same as above

Comment: Try removing the `codecs` from the ogg video. The extra `&quot;`s may be messing you up.

Comment: Thanks i have tried that. same issue

Comment: Maybe your ogg video is formatted incorrectly? I use the following format regularly and it always works for me https://gist.github.com/dyladan/5442401

Comment: i have used VLC to convert them, tried the link you have provided and still the same errors

Comment: They all run fine in vlc player, but not in the broswers

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

the slashes above are the wrong ones, it should be / now all is fine in all browsers apart from I.E 10, no errors just does not run